# How Do I Open app service firewall for itself

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-appservice

I could use some guidance here.
I'm trying to find the correct script for a azurerm_app_service.
I need to open its firewall, such that it is open for itself.
I have tried:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "cms" {
  resource_group_name                           = azurerm_resource_group.shared.name
```

...

```
dynamic "ip_restriction" {
  for_each = split(",", azurerm_app_service.cms.possible_outbound_ip_addresses)
  content {
    ip_address = format("%s/32", ip_restriction.value)
    name       = azurerm_app_service.cms.name
    priority   = 100
  }
}
```

But I get:

```
╷
│ Error: Self-referential block
│
│   on Cms.tf line 66, in resource "azurerm_app_service" "cms":
│   66:         name       = azurerm_app_service.cms.name
│
│ Configuration for azurerm_app_service.cms may not refer to itself.
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to grab all outbound IP in form of array or something ?

Comment: I want to open up, such that the website can call itself...